# Need a Four Criteria Index Match - Three Semi-Works, I add the Fourth Criteria and it Breaks

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, criteria, index-match

I've got one sheet that has all four criteria in individual columns, and the report that I drop into a new sheet each day is staggered in a horrible way (I didn't design it). For security reasons I can't give the actual data, but I've attached a [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maNB8.png) of what I'm dealing with (consolidated to one sheet for simplicity). I need to match all four criteria in each row in columns A:D, and then return the annual amount from column X, straight across from the matching in column O - The Label Type doesn't have to match, as those #'s stay the same and that would add a 5th criteria when I'm already struggling with four. The issue is that criteria can repeat under different columns with different other criteria (See O13 vs O25 for example).

[image]
Goal in mind is that for F4, I would need it to return X15, as that is the Unissued Amount for #1 Funds, with G1 = 1C, G2 = AB, and G3 = A1.

My very not right but best working formula is this, which basically is just a fancy V-Lookup for column O.

```
=INDEX($I$1:$X$27,
IF(MATCH($A2,J:J,0)*MATCH($B2,M:M,0)*MATCH($C2,N:N,0)*MATCH($D2,O:O,0),
(MATCH($D2,O:O,0))),
MATCH($X$12,$I$12:$X$12,0))
```

Edit to add: the drop in report is dynamic and the location of the criteria can change up or down in the columns.

Comment: the best method would be to fill in the empty cells with the correct data, then you can use SUMIFS to return the correct number.

Comment: Thank you Scott. The drop in report is quite a bit longer than my little example here, so I was hoping for a way around the manual entry of data. Fact is the report our system generates is super unfriendly data-wise and I may be entering stuff manually whether I want to or not.

Comment: There are many examples of code out there that will fill empty cells with the value above it.  You can run that after import to normalize the data.  Then it would be easier to use formula on the data.

Comment: Make a table out of your data and use power query >> transform >> fill down on the first few columns. Then it's easier to reference. Else you could use something like `=INDEX(X:X,MATCH(1,(A2=J:J)*(B2=M:M)(C2,N:N)*(D2=O:O),0)+SEQUENCE(3,,0))`

Answer (score 1):

To do a multi-value INDEX/MATCH, take advantage if the fact that `TRUE` and `FALSE` can be treated as `1` and `0`, and invert the MATCH to find the value `1`.

So, to match values A2, B2, C2, and D2 to columns J, M, N, and O, you would use this:

```
=INDEX($X:$X, MATCH(1, ($A2=$J:$J)*($B2=$M:$M)*($C2=$N:$N)*($D2=$O:$O), 0))
```

However, that won't work in this case, because you have no values in the cells M14:P15, M17:P18, M20:P21, M23:P24, nor M26:P27 — so there's nothing for the `MATCH` to… well, match.

And, since you are returning Numerical values — without duplicate rows — rather than text values, you might as well just use a `SUMIFS` instead of a multi-INDEX/MATCH, **once** you've fixed the table:

```
=SUMIFS($X:$X, $J:$J,$A2, $M:$M,$B2, $N:$N,$C2, $O:$O,$D2)
```

(Of course, if the data looked like that because it was in a PivotTable, you could use the `GETPIVOTDATA` function.  If you are copy/pasting the data *from* a PivotTable, just go to the "Design" tab, then "Report Layout" and "Repeat All Item Labels" before you copy/paste the table over!)